# isEven function wierd way

Tags: javascript, function

I was playing around with on of the excercises when I coded this:

```
function isEven(x){
   var m = x % 2
   var n = x / 2
   return m <= !n
}
```

The funny part is that it actually works, but I do not understand if !n makes the number negative or affects the boolean value itself. Can someone explain how my code works? Thanks.

Comment: You could debug this code and figure it out.

Comment: Your function doesn't work correctly with negative arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`!n` is a red herring. For any value of `x` other than `0`, `!n` will be `false`; it will be `true` when `x == 0`.

`m` is `0` for even numbers, `1` for odd numbers. When you compare a number with a boolean, the boolean is converted to a number. So `m <= false` is equivalent to `m <= 0`. This will be true when `m` is `0`.

So you can get rid of `n` and just use this:

```js
function isEven(x){
   var m = x % 2;
   return m <= false
}

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].forEach(x => console.log(x, isEven(x)));
```

The reason why it works with `!n` is because in the only case where `!n` is `true`, `x == 0` and `m == 0`. `0 <= true` is true, so the function returns the correct result then as well.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
var n = x / 2
```

`n` will be falsey if x is 0, and truthy otherwise.

If the argument is even and not 0:

- m will be 0
- n will be a truthy number (because anything divided by 2 is another non-zero number - except 0)
- !n will be false (because that's the boolean inverse of 0, a falsey value)
- the return statement is 0 <= false; false [gets converted into a number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan) when compared with <=, and 0 <= 0 is true

If the argument is odd and positive:

- m will be 1
- n will be truthy (because any odd number divided by 2 is another non-zero number, and a non-zero number is truthy)
- !n will be false (because that's the boolean inverse of a truthy value)
- the return statement is 1 <= false; false gets converted into a number when compared with <=, and 1 <= 0 is false

If the argument is even and 0:

- m will be 0
- n will be 0
- !n will be true (boolean inverse of 0)
- the return statement is 0 <= true; true [gets converted into a number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan) when compared with <=, and 0 <= 1 is true

But the code doesn't work when the argument is odd and negative, because a negative odd number `% 2` gives -1, not 1.

- m will be -1
- n will be truthy (because any odd number divided by 2 is another non-zero number, and a non-zero number is truthy)
- !n will be false (because that's the boolean inverse of a truthy value)
- the return statement is -1 <= false; false gets converted into a number when compared with <=, and -1 <= 0 is true - **when it should be false**

Comment: Why are you doing `0/2` and `1/2`? `n` is `x/2`, not `m/2`.